# Google login API: force to type password?

Tags: php, google-api, google-signin, google-php-sdk

I'm using several social providers on my site, including Google. I would like to ask for password to Google account each time user requests one of my actions. This is for security reasons.

With Facebook, we can send `auth_type=reauthenticate` parameter. Is there something like this in Google API?

I'm not looking for refreshing tokens, I need to make sure user types his password at any state: whether already authenticated or not.

Comment: My recommendation is you don't do this. Users will find it really annoying. You should either trust the user and Google to keep their account safe or you should implement your own password system.

Comment: I wanted to do it in Sign Up feature instead of e-mail confirmation, I don't think it's very annoying.

Comment: Another use-case is "sudo mode" - like adding new ssh key on github.

Answer (score 4):

I read your posts and I can relate to your frustration on this matter (including some of poor responses inline above).

You want to be able to prompt users to reauthenticate with Google in order to prove that the user behind the computer is indeed the account holder.  Having required similar functionality myself, I've concluded that they do not implement it.  This creates a problem of trust for an application that relies on a Google login for access, but also provides some destructive functionality which should require a reaffirmation of the identity of the user.  Wish I had better news for you.

Having implemented this feature with Facebook's API, I was certain Google would provide similar since it's so essential to security, however they don't.

Comment: Thank you, I think you are totally right. On both lack of this feature in Google and on quality of responses above :D

Comment: I creating app for below 13, and require parents to sign up for them so there's a need to reverify password when it gets tot he "parents" session. It's now 2020, and google still don't have option for this. Frustrating.

Comment: Related question (also with no answers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46704603/using-google-auth2-sign-in-force-user-to-enter-password