# Firebase: How to always force a sign-in?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication

Working in Eclipse, & using the [provided methods](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth) in Firebase' docs, I was able to setup logins for several providers such as Google and Facebook, using the redirect option. I basically click on a button for the provider on my web page, & it takes me to the login screen where I can enter a UID and password (e.g. Google sign-in)

However, once I authenticate properly with a valid account, and even if I sign-out, I get logged into the same account, without ever getting the screen prompting to log in. Where is this information persisted? Closing out Eclipse, or turning the computer off, does nothing to help, so I believe this is all being saved somewhere.

How do I "forget" previous attempts, so that I can see a provider's log in screen, each and every time?

Comment: Does anyone have any more input? It seems to me that there should be a mechanism in Firebase to do this, since it would be unusable in a public setting, such as an internet cafe, or library.

Comment: Related question, also without answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433378/google-login-api-force-to-type-password

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use setCustomParameters on AuthProviders.
For example, in the case of Google: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider#setCustomParameters

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({prompt: 'select_account'});
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
```

This will not forget the previous attempt but it will prompt the user to select an existing account or a new one.

Comment: Thanks @bojeil, but it still automatically logs in, if an account that was previously authenticated, is selected. Isn't this a glaring issue with regard to security? How are public locations like libraries, or internet cafes, handled? There must be a way to prevent login information from persisting.

Comment: This is specific to Google. You have to log out the user from their google first party account. If this is a concern. You can redirect to the google logout page on sign out.