# Using Google auth2 sign in, force user to enter password

Tags: javascript, google-api-js-client, google-signin

I just implemented Google JavaScript sign-in button to our homepage, and everything works the way it suppose to, but thats sometimes bad..

So the thing is that our users use our application on the same computer, 3-4 different users per day. Having a google sign in gives us access to implement some Google product features in our own site.

I understand that sign-in with google signs you into the Google account, and also gives permission to application.
Also i understand that this is the way it works to make the life easier for user, not to sign in each time on every site.

I can easily remove the application permission via `GoogleAuth.signOut()` or `GoogleUser.disconnect()`, even with `GoogleAuth.disconnect()`, so the `.isSignedIn()` will become false, so the user will always have the prompt screen, also i use `prompt: 'select_account'` on `.signIn()` to make sure even single user will get the prompt screen.

The problem is when the 2nd user enters to our login screen and chooses "Sign in with Google", he can actually choose any previous user in the prompt screen and enter into our application as not himself, but actually can choose the previous user and authenticate himself as the other **without entering any password**.
Password will be only asked if previous user also logs out from his Goole account.

I know a hack is to redirect user to URL:
`https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=YOUR_REDIRECT_URL`
But thats seems like a very poor solution, because our users use our application also with their personal devices, so its kind of bad if they get logged out from all applications they have signed into.

I know asking password on each sign in is not the way auth2 intended to work, but i'm sure there is a way forcing user to enter password on each time they press "sing in with google" button.

Ive spend multiple hours on searching for a solution and tried multiple things, i hope someone of you can point out the needle in the haystack that i missed

Comment: I am struggling with this same issue.  Did you ever find a way to secure account access on machines where multiple users frequently work?

Comment: I don't know a solution to your question (I wish I did). However, one thing you might do is require some form of second factor on your site (e.g., a TOTP code) in addition to the Google sign-in.

Comment: Related question, also with no answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433378/google-login-api-force-to-type-password