# Android Google SSO - Force User to Enter Password

Tags: android, single-sign-on, google-sso

I'm interested in using Google SSO in my Java-based Android app, so that the users don't have another account and password to remember, but - given the sensitive nature of some of the data in the app - I'd like to force users to re-enter their Google password each time they log in (rather than just allowing them to unlock the phone and then tap on the SSO buttons). Is this currently possible?

(I see this question was asked before - [Using Google auth2 sign in, force user to enter password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46704603/using-google-auth2-sign-in-force-user-to-enter-password) and [Google login API: force to type password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433378/google-login-api-force-to-type-password), for example - but the only [negative] responses I see are from years ago, so I'm *hoping* this has gained support since then.)